# How to retrieve all data for a specific location from database

Tags: haskell

I am new to Haskell and trying to obtain a list of spa in a specific location in haskell. I manage to create list of location into String but I am not sure regarding the final gathering portion from database. I try linking but it give me these error

1st error

```
* Couldn't match type `[Char]' with `Spa -> [Char]'
  Expected type: Spa -> [Char]
    Actual type: String
* Possible cause: `locationListStr' is applied to too many arguments
  In the first argument of `map', namely
    `(locationListStr spaLocation)'
  In the first argument of `concat', namely
    `(map (locationListStr spaLocation) database)'
  In the expression:
    concat (map (locationListStr spaLocation) database)
```

This is my code below.

```
type SpaID = String
type Name = String
type Location = String
type Popularity = Int
type Massager =  String 
type SkillRating = Int 

data Spa = Spa SpaID Name Location Popularity [(Massager, SkillRating)]

type Database = [Spa]

Database :: [Spa]


Database = [
                Spa  "01" " Amador" "Orchard" 3 
                [("Bryan", 7)],

                Spa  "02" "Basque Spa by Aitor" "Tanjong Pagar" 1 
                [("Colin", 9), ("Sam", 8)],
                
                Spa  "03" "Beni" "Orchard" 1 [("Julien", 9)]
           ]

-- turn list of location into a string
locationListStr :: [Location] -> String
locationListStr = intercalate "\n"

-- retrieve on all data from database for spa at certain location
spaLocationListStr :: [Location] -> [Spa] -> String
spaLocationListStr spaLocation database = concat(map (locationListStr spaLocation) database)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that function `map` has this type:

```
map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
```

and when you wrote `map (locationListStr spaLocation) database`, `locationListStr spaLocation` has type `String` and it isn't function.

And I don't understand what function `spaLocationListStr` must doing. You wrote above on the first sentence that you are trying to obtain a list of spa in a specific location. So, if I understand you correctly, you need a function like this:

```
getLocation :: Spa -> Location
getLocation (Spa _ _ location _ _) = location

spaInLocation :: Location -> [Spa] -> [Spa]
spaInLocation location = filter ((== location) . getLocation)
```

So, please, refine, what function `spaLocationListStr` must do. Can you write some examples what your function should return?

Comment: in the terminal, it should show the list of spa with the location like "Orchard". 

 [Spa "03" "John" "Orchard" 6 [],Spa "10" "Sally" "Orchard" 11 []]

I am sorry about that horrible code I did up there. But it should be retrieving from the entire database.

Comment: OK, then function `spaInLocation` is what you need) For example, `spaInLocation "Orchard" Database` return list `[Spa  "01" " Amador" "Orchard" 3 [("Bryan", 7)]], Spa  "03" "Beni" "Orchard" 1 [("Julien", 9)]]`